# Issues with network stability

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch, google-wifi

I can't seem to manage to sort out my home network issues. I have a setup that looks like this:

[image]

So I have a router that is set up to just be a bridge, and DHCP and everything is disabled on it. It is connected to a Google WiFi that is set to work as my DVCP server, and that is connected to a switch, that switch is then connected to another Google WiFi from one port, and from another port it's connected to another switch (located in the basement), and that switch is branched out to two additional Google WiFi units. All the secondary Google WiFi units are connected to a PC using a cable.

All cables in the setup is CAT-6 cables. Two of the cables I have put on the plug in one end myself to get the cable through the wall, but I have a cable tester that confirms that the cable is ok. The two switches are of this type: https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg105e/#specifications

The problem is that usually the network works just fine. I usually get a good ping, but it sometimes are a bit varied. So ping usually is between 6ms and 20ms, but then it suddenly spike over 100ms several pings in a row, then some pings are not returned at all, and the network is down for some seconds. Then it's back to 6-20ms again. It seems to happen more frequently when there are many devices connected to and actively using the network.

If I just connect one PC to the primary Google WiFi like this, everything works fine and the ping is constant on 2ms. So I know that the problem is in my local network and not my ISP or something like that:

[image]

Could it be that the problem is the two routers? That some loops occur? Could it be a problem with the cable even if the cable tester shows green? Would it not then not work at all?

I'm not that into networking when it get's specific like this, so I'm not at all sure how to debug this issue and solve it. Hope some of you recognize these symptoms and can help me.

Comment: See https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/

Comment: Try replacing the second router (lower one in your diagram) with a good but simple unmanaged switch to see if that helps.